# Update dynamoDB column using condition expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to update existing item of dynamoDB table using condition equivalent to like (%) condition of sql

### opIdUserId status

- 123-U1       inprogress
- 345-U2       inprogress
- 123-U3       onhold

opIdUserId in my dynamodb is **Primary partition key**. I want to update status to COMP for opIdUserId field value starting from or contains 123.

this is what I am trying currently but researched and found I can not use KeyConditionExpression for update.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
 const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'}); 
 var table = "tablename";

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    var params = {
    TableName: table,

    KeyConditionExpression: "begins_with(opIdUserId, :i)",
    UpdateExpression: "set operationStatus = :o",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":o":"COMP",
        ":i":"123-"
    },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {

         callback(err, null);
    } else {
         callback(null,data); 

    }
});
 }
```

Please suggest how I can update my item in dynamoDB with specific condition.

Comment: You should scan for all items that match your key condition expression and then update them, item by item.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html) on your table to `query` for the items that start with `123` using a `KeyConditionExpression`.

```
var params = {
  TableName: table,
  KeyConditionExpression: "id = :id AND begins_with(opIdUserId, :opIdUserId)",
  UpdateExpression: "set operationStatus = :operationStatus",
  ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ":opIdUserId":"123-",
    ":id": "something"
  }
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(data);
});
```

Bare in mind that you can't run a query using `BEGINS_WITH` on a `partition key`, only on a `sort key`.

Then, you can use the `update` method over every individual element using the `partition and sort key` for the table, updating the `operationStatus`.

If you provide me with information regarding your `DynamoDB` table, I could help you create the `GSI`.